# Login authentication problem with firebase in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-authentication

I try to do firebase authenticate. I've installed all necessary pods and made all needed methods. When I click "Login" even when I entered bad email and password, I get error message (e.g. bad password) and immediately my view is changed to my target view (next ViewController). I don't know why it is happening, because I made if statement. I want to have my login page unless I enter correct email and password.

```
 @IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
         if let email = emailTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines), let password =
 passwordTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in:
 .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
             
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
                if let e = error {
                     // Can't sign in
                     self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
                     self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
                 } else {
                     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToHome", sender: self)
                }
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: How you have added segue to move to next controller upon success ?

Comment: I have added it by mainstoryboard. I have dragged login button to new View and added segue "show" with identifier "loginToHome"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to check if an error exists first. If yes, the error message will be shown. If there's no error, the login success segue will be performed.

```
@IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let email = emailTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines), let password = passwordTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
          if error != nil { // there's an error - show error label
               self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
               self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
          } else { //no error - perform segue
           // no error - perform segue
          self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToHome", sender: self) } } } }
```

**Edit**: You may also add `return` after checking that an error exists - the codes that follow after it will not be performed:

```
@IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let email = emailTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines), let password = passwordTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
          if error != nil { // there's an error - show error label
                self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
                self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
                return // activities that follow will not be performed
          } else { //no error - perform segue
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToHome", sender: self) } } } }
```

Comment: Have you tried this code snippet before voting down? pls explain the downvote.

Comment: Ok, I've tried this, but it still doesn't work :(. It automatically moves to next view when I click login button

Comment: Maybe better option will be add instantiate view?

Comment: are you using the UIStoryboard or are you doing the views programmatically? If you are using the Storyboard, are you sure your UIButton is not connected to the next View?

Comment: I use UIStoryboard and its connected (segue push)

Comment: have you connected the segue via UIButton (login button) or via the UIViewController itself (UIViewController to UIViewController)?

Comment: If your segue is connected via the UIButton then it must be the problem...

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem :)! But could you tell me why it happens (when I connect it with button (like in my code) it doesn't work? I use if statement, so else statement should not be perform if first statement was true).

Comment: Hello @kacper99, i'm glad that it worked for you. Anyway, what's happening was that the connection you've made in the UIStoryBoard (from the UIButton to the UIViewController (VC)) gets called EVERYTIME you click on the button, thus, the if-else statement you have is not ignored, but is nonetheless called at the same time your Views are segued to the Next VC. What you need is to connect your segues from VC to VC, not UIButtons to VC. That way, your if-else condition will be prioritized.

Comment: If i helped in some way, pls mark my answer as the solution, thank you!